# Regex for getting data within braces in java

Tags: java, regex

I need a proper regex more specifically in Java to get strings between `[]`.

**String:**

```
[2015-04-09 13:10:27,858] [1428599427721] [{ashwinsakthi@yahoo.com}{SpringFramework}{Host123}{58}{20150409131026660}][getfilesInput] [WebContainer : 2]
```

I need to print in the below format:

```
2015-04-09 13:10:27,858
1428599427721
ashwinsakthi@yahoo.com
etc..
```

Tried the regular expression `\\[(.*?)\\]` as shown below, but it is not working.

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\[(.*?)\\]");
```

Comment: Could you format a bit better? I am not sure to understand what your input format is, and how you are recovering the matches from your regex.

Comment: try `Pattern.compile("\\[[^]]*\\]");`

Comment: @SashaSalauyou shouldn't the `?` that he uses make it ungreedy ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code will correctly extract all those values inside `[]`s and `{}`s:

```
String str = "[2015-04-09 13:10:27,858] [1428599427721] [{ashwinsakthi@yahoo.com}{SpringFramework}{Host123}{58}{20150409131026660}][getfilesInput] [WebContainer : 2]";
String rx = "[\\[{]+([^\\]}]*?)[\\]}]+";
Pattern ptrn = Pattern.compile(rx);
Matcher m = ptrn.matcher(str);
while (m.find()) {
   System.out.println(m.group(1));
}
```

Output:

```
2015-04-09 13:10:27,858                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
1428599427721                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
ashwinsakthi@yahoo.com                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
SpringFramework                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
Host123                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
58                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
20150409131026660                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
getfilesInput                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
WebContainer : 2
```

**EDIT**

The main problem with the original regex is that it only captures what is inside square brackets (see [demo](https://regex101.com/r/fT4vR4/1)), while we need to match everything in-between curly braces and square brackets.

Comment: The question wasn't really to parse using the "{}" delimiters. It's only to parse using the "[]" delimiters. Personally, I am still curious what's wrong with ashiwinsakthi's regex.

Comment: @bvdb: As I understood, the question was about retrieving strings inside curly and square brackets. There is an infinite number of what the question was not about :). I added an explanation and a demo of the original regex.